# get value based on following node

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<new>
This is content <star.page>21</star.page> with star pages <star.page>22</star.page> inside it.
</new>
<main>
    This is main content
</main>
</root>
```

Here i want to print the number whose following is `main`, i.e. want to print only `22` but no 21.

I want to get this done from `star.page` template. like here, `21` is followed by `22`(both are `star.page`), i want to print `star.page` value where there is `main` following this and there is no other `star.page` in between. here in my input between `21` and `main` there is another `star.page` but not between `22` and `main`. so i want to print `22` but not `21`. and this template must be done inside `template match="star.page"`, but not from the `root`.

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix it.

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ8)

Comment: Please include relevant code (only) and desired output into your question.

Comment: Provide such input or test with those cases, and let us know.

Comment: @RudramuniTP, this is the sample that i've provided from my code. Can you please modify my `if` to match my requirement

Comment: See my updates below ANSWER area, where 24 is last page, not the 23, because 24 page is having following MAIN element.

Comment: Alter u r input accordingly, explain clearly or place the required output.

Comment: Place u r complete required out put text. Above is explanation.

Comment: See my answer now, I updated to template match for star.page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

XML:

```
<root>
<new>
This is content <star.page>21</star.page> with star pages <star.page>22</star.page> inside it.
</new>
<main>
    This is main content
</main>

</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="star.page">
       <xsl:if test="following::*[name()='main'] and not(following::*[name()='star.page'])">
           <xsl:text>Last page is </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(name()='star.page')]/text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OutPut:

```
Last page is 22
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but there are even more star.page, want to try it like, get page number where, main is followed by a star.page and not any other star.page in between

Comment: Here in the example there are just 2 page numbers and based on your xslt, it prints only last `star.page` but, in my XML there are `star.page` inside `main` also, i want to print only the last `star.page` whose following is `main`, and want it to do using `star.page template`

Comment: I mean is there a way where i can match `star.page` and see `following::main`

Comment: @user3872094, Welcome, in future posts, place u r tried XSLT, by that at we can try thru u r code itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to be to use `preceding` when navigating from `main`, and find the last `star.page`, irrespective of the rest of the structure:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(/root/main/preceding::star.page)[position()=last()]"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ8/1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but there are even more `star.page`, want to try it like, `get page number where, main is followed by a star.page and not any other star.page in between`

Comment: Can you update your example to show an example of what you mean? This (and your fiddle) seem to meet the criteria `print the number whose following is main, i.e. want to print only 22 but no 21.`

Comment: Here in the example there are just 2 page numbers and based on your xslt, it prints only last `star.page` but, in my XML there are `star.page` inside `main` also, i want to print only the last `star.page` whose following is `main`, and want it to do using `star.page template`